# Consciousness and neural grafting

Tags: consciousness, philosophy-of-mind

You have two friends: Alice and Bob. Suppose you have a way to remove a healthy neuron from Alice's brain and conserve it in some safe place. And, viceversa, suppose you have a way to graft this neuron in a certain region of Bob's brain (assuming the new neuron will develop connections with the others nearby).

Then keep repeating the following two steps:

- remove one neuron from Alice and another from Bob, both possibly from the same region;
- graft Alice's neuron in Bob's brain and viceversa (again, both in the same region)

until all neurons have been exchanged.

After we have exchanged all the neurons, **will Alice and Bob still feel the same?** If so, consider this: let `v` be the speed at which we complete the entire operation, with `v = 1` meaning instant exchange and `v = 0` meaning infinite time (no exhange at all). **What would be the maximum possible value of `v` such that Bob and Alice still feel the same after the operation?**

Comment: Interesting question that has been around for a long time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on science fiction and not rooted in scientific knowledge.